# How to check if date picker is opened or closed in view SwiftUI. without Tap Gesture on Date picker

Tags: ios, swift, date, swiftui, picker

When the user hits date picker in swiftUI, it opens up and shows calendar to choose date user may or may not choose date and user hits somewhere else in the view and date picker closes it self. I want to change date picker parent view border when user hits date picker and also when user tap somewhere else screen date picker closes and its parent view border does not changes.I want to handle the date picker parent view border color. when then date picker is closed or dismissed.[image: this date picker in parent view] [image: changing date picker parent view border color on tap gesture][image: date picker dismissed/closed but unable to detect when date picker is closed.]

```
DatePicker("", selection: $datePicker, displayedComponents: .date)
                    .labelsHidden()
                    .padding(.trailing, 8)
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)
                    .colorMultiply(AppColors.textNavy100Color)
                    .accentColor(AppColors.textNavy100Color)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("date picker tapped")
                        if isFieldEditing == false{
                            isFieldEditing = true
                        }else {
                           isFieldEditing = false
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You don't look for changes to the DatePicker view, you look for changes to the selected date. So use for instance `onChange` on your `$datePicker` property.

Comment: well, I have to adopt it there is more options left. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever figured it out? I am facing the same problem as you.

Comment: Not yet but its a default behaviour, you may proceed with default or you can make a custom view for date picker and add a done button in it.